# Purpose of the firefox-4 tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Jorge Castro brought this up in chat a few days ago so I'm opening a discussion: Do we need the [firefox-4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox-4) AND [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox) tags? I don't think [firefox-4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox-4) offers any additional data that couldn't be derived from the [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox) tag. It would be like having [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox), [firefox-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox-2), [firefox-3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox-3) they are all [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox)

Opinions, suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Merge

I think the [firefox-4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox-4) should be merged with [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox) since it does not offer any additional value other than being a meta tag.

Comment: definitely merge, "version tags for the sake of version tags" is always dangerous and should be eradicated like the weed it is..

Comment: @JeffAtwood Thanks, Killed with fire.

Comment: Also, with the accelerated release cycle, we'd be collecting firefox-N tags pretty quickly. (Every 6 weeks iirc?)

Comment: Merger it is. Before Firefox 4 was released, it was useful because many wanted to try out the beta and RC releases.

Comment: @Christoph, I don't think it will have much impact, since they're not *major releases*. Before the accelerated schedule each version brought great changes which was why many were interested, but now there won't be as much hype with things And the tags will be just like Google Chrome's.